# Selection radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Am a bit stuck on where to go from here. I would like my radio button(s) to return the value of the selected button. But right now, its only return the value of the first item. How can I make it loop through all the values, here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php include 'db_connector.php';
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM os_scope");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $row['name'];
            echo "<input type='radio' name='os' value=".$row['name']." id='myRadio'>";
        }
    ?>

    <p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the radio button.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myRadio").value;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementsByName('os');
        var rate_value;
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            if(x[i].checked){
                rate_value = x[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rate_value;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much, that worked exactly the way I want it to.

Comment: How can I use the returned id value to write a mysql query using the code above?                                                      SELECT * FROM os WHERE scope='id';

Answer (score 1):

Try this : iterate all radio button with name="os" and then check which one has `checked` attribute true.

**NOTE** - `id`s must be unique always hence use different `id` for different radio button.

```
function myFunction() {
    var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName("os");
    var x = '';
    for(var i=0;i<radiobutton.length;i++)
    {
       if(radiobutton[i].checked)
         x = radiobutton[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much help this has been for me.

Comment: How can I use the returned id value to write a mysql query using the code above? Something like...                                         SELECT * FROM os WHERE scope='id'                                     'id' is the returned value from the radio button.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of: An element Id should be unqiue `id='myRadio'` in a while loop wont be unique.

i would suggest using [class](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/) (instead of `id`) and [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/) (for-css like selectors in javascript):

```js
function getSelectedRadioValue() {
  alert($('.myRadio:checked').first().val());
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type='radio' name='os' value="1" class='myRadio'>1
  <input type='radio' name='os' value="2" class='myRadio'>2
  <input type='radio' name='os' value="3" class='myRadio'>3

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the radio button.</p>
  <button onclick="getSelectedRadioValue()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

## ajax Example

Ajax is a synchronious server calls and they return data you can use in jquery on your website. For example:

```js
function sendMessage() {

  $.post("your url to serverside script you want to execute.php"
  , { 'Index': 'Data Found in $_Post'} //in execute.php $_POST['Index'] will now contain: 'Data Found in $_Post'
  , function(data) {
    //in data will be the stuff you echo-ed in your php script (if you used json_encode($data) in php this will be automatically detected and converted to a javascript object.
    $("$body").html(data); //for instance we get html from the AJAX call (execute.php) and insert in the #body div
  }).fail(function(){
    alert('The server returned an error'); //ofcourse server returns an error, because URL used in this example does not exist
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">

</div>

<button onclick="sendMessage()">execute AJAX call</button>
```

Comment: How can I use the returned id value to write a mysql query using the code above? Something like...                                         SELECT * FROM os WHERE scope='id'                                     'id' is the returned value from the radio button.. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Submit the form or use AJAX. (do it serverside in php)

Comment: sorry to be a pest, but am getting all kinds of things here, could you show me an example using AJAX. Thanks

Comment: See my example, although you should read some tutorial or elaboration about AJAX, not just use my code and run.

Comment: I tried the following example, could you help me check, what am doing wrong. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713629/sending-radio-button-value-using-ajax-to-get-php-file-to-retrieve-data-from-mysq/26762687?noredirect=1#comment42130042_26762687). Really appreciate all the help this far.