# Sending radio button value using AJAX to get PHP file to retrieve data from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, radio-button

I want to be able to write a few mysql queries with the returned value(s) of my radio button(s). Here is the code I have

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str=="") {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

                <?php include 'db_connector.php';

                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM os_scope");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $row['name'];

                echo "<li><div class='toggle-btn-grp cssonly'>

                        <div><form><input type='radio' name='os' value=".$row['name']." id='myRadio' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>

                        <label class='toggle-btn'><div class='title'>".$row['name']."</form></div></label></div></div></li>";

            }

                ?>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php file getuser.php

```
  <?php
  $q = intval($_GET['q']);

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','abc123','mydb');
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
  $sql="SELECT * FROM os ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Scope</th>
  <th>Client</th>
  <th>Supplier</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['scope'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['client'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['supplier'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
```

However, when I run the code I keep getting this error:
**Notice: Undefined index: q**
Which means q is not been sent to the php file, any ideas how I can fix this?
I would really appreciate all the help I can get. Sorry if this is a dumb question but am really new at this, so I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?=q"+str,true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
```

The `q` and `=` are the wrong way around ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I've made the changes you suggested, but am still getting the error ** Notice: Undefined index: q ** I get the same error when i run the php file alone as well.

Comment: Are you including a value for `q` in the query string? E.g. in your browser access `getuser.php?q=123`

Comment: Also, in your example code, you have a closing php tag after `mysqli_close` but then some more PHP. This will also cause unexpected behaviour... If the additional PHP after the closing tag is meant to be there, you should remove the closing PHP tag after `mysqli_close`.

Comment: @joel harkes I tried the following example could you help me to point out where am going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Annie - I think you posted on the wrong answer! Did you mean to post on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26606102/940252)? :)

Comment: oops sorry, my apologises.

Comment: referring to your comment about 'including a value for q in the query string', am not sure I understand. I want q to contain the value of the selected radio button, and then send it to the php file and then I can use it in the query.

Comment: Yes, my code sample in this answer will do that when `getuser.php` is requested by AJAX - it will pass the radio button value to `getuser.php` via the query string. But when you run `getuser.php` alone in your browser (just for testing) you will need to provide the value of `q` yourself in the query string, or it will not know what to use for `q`, and you will see this error.

Comment: I feel reading some tutorials on query strings might help you. See [this tutorial](http://www.tiposaurus.co.uk/php/basics/use-the-query-string/) :)

Comment: Cheers, I'll read through the tutorial. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Excellent! Please accept this answer and enjoy using query strings. :)